# How to combine 2 return values in php?

Tags: php, arrays, function, return

How can I combine 2 return values in php?

I have the following 2 functions with return values I need to combine into one operation.

Function #1

```
function my_callback1($var_name) {
    return get_theme_mod($var_name);
}
```

Function #2

```
function my_callback2($var_name, $arr_key) {
    $font = get_theme_mod($var_name);
    return $font[$arr_key];
}
```

I need `return get_theme_mod($var_name);` and `return $font[$arr_key];` to return in the same instance.

Comment: `return array(my_callback1(..), my_callback2(..));`?

Comment: Be more descriptive in what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write something like,

```
function fun1('something1'){
    -------
    -------
    return $r1;
}
function fun2('something2'){
    --------
    --------
    return $r2;
}
function total('something'){
    $fun1_return = fun1();
    $fun2_return = fun2();
    return array($fun1_return, $fun2_return);
}
```

it will give you desired output.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the long delay on this. This was more difficult for me to figure out then and couldn;'t get it work, but it was probably me I'm sure. I've since matured in php and chose your answer because it was best explained in its writing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Return an array?

```
function combined($var_name, $arr_key)
{
     return array('var_name' =>$var_name, 'font'=> $font);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return an array :

```
function combine($var_name, $arr_key) {
    $font = get_theme_mod($var_name);
    return array('font' => $font[$arr_key], 'getResult'=> get_theme_mod($var_name));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an array as return-value instead.

EG:

```
function whatever($arg1, $arg2){
   // do stuff
   return array("firstResult" => 123, "secondResult" => 456);
}
```

Then when you call it:

```
$myResult = whatever(1,"tralala");
```

now you have:

```
$myResult["firstResult"]
and
$myResult["secondResult"]
```